# Layout of Annotated Posts is broken in Firefox

Tags: support, design, moderator-tools

When I click on the "show full question" on the "Annotated Posts" page of the [LEGO Answers](http://bricks.stackexchange.com) mod tools in Firefox 10 and 11 I see the following odd behaviour:

[image: Whoops, where's the question gone?]

This isn't happening in IE9 or Chrome.

I've checked my zoom levels, and that doesn't seem to have any effect, and it's happening for all questions on this page.

Other pages with similar features (i.e. the review tools, etc.) all seem to be working OK.

Combining Shog9's exemplary use of 3D with freehand highlights we can see that there appears to be an issue does indeed seem to be happening with the `<div class="cbt question-summary">` container:

[image: div.cbt.question-summary]

Also, is this page supposed to be open access given that it's only really linked to from the mod tools?

Having noticed that this page is open access, I've taken a look at a few other sites, and can report that it also only appears to affecting the Sketchy theme (I can reproduce this on Astronomy but not on Board and Card Games, nor Gaming), so I'm happy for this to be marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) if that's easier, seeing as Sketchy's on its way out.

Comment: I got the same problems with Firefox11, and also the "Add Comment" doesn't work in Stackoverflow, but in meta it works (obviously)

Comment: "*This isn't happening in IE9*" I just felt great disturbance in the Source, as if millions of firefox fanbois suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced...

Comment: @Won't I see, it all makes sense now ;)

Comment: 3... 2... 1... until George Edison's FHC script gets 3D effects

Comment: Your red lines will need to be in 3D for us to see what they're pointing to...

Comment: @NickCraver: As requested sir, I hope that's clearer ;)

Comment: @balpha: Er... do [anaglyph images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image) count?

Comment: @balpha: ...also, see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zGB.png).

Answer (score 6):

Reproduced. **IN 3D!**

[image: Ok, I gotta admit, this is pretty gimmicky... But 3D DOM is enough to make checking it fun]

Looks like Firefox doesn't like the "question summary" floating left...

Comment: Curses. I drew the freeahand highlighting deliberately for Meta, but forgot to use Tilt!